# How reshape a Matrix in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Please I need your help for a problem

```
import tensorflow 

import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist


(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

I want to convert x_train that has (60000,28,28) to (60000,784) please help me; thank you in advance.

I try this code but dont get what i want :

```
np.reshape(x_train,(60000,784),order='f')


dimensions=np.shape(x_train)

print(dimensions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i found the answer:

```
x_train=np.reshape(x_train,(60000,784),order='C')

dimensions=np.shape(x_train)

print(dimensions)
```